# Unable to format data taken from web-service

Tags: c#, web-services, layout

I'm calling data from the web-service however i was not able to format the position of the data i retrieve properly in a multi-line text. This is how it looks like when i directly call the data from the web-service

[image]

Supposely, the data was meant to be formatted in this way.

`IncomeShield(1-12)`

`IncomeShield(31-above)`

so on and so forth. This is how i call the data from the web-service

`txthistoryD.Text += ddlCode.SelectedValue.ToString()`

I attempt to add a `<br / >` after calling the value but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other method where i can format my data properly?

Comment: Did you try `Environment.Newline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here < br /> tag will not work becuase this is asp.net server side control. You have to use \n escape sequence to format this as mentioned below:

```
  txthistoryD.Text += ddlCode.SelectedValue.ToString() + "\n";
```